# File provider configuration for image capture

Tags: android

I want to capture image with camera, I attaching image path for capture output.
I want to store the image in `images` folder inside external storage `getExternalFilesDir`.

Like this:

`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packagename/files/images/21_4_2021_14_23_24.png`

I cannot understand how should look the file provider paths to give access to my `images` folder, currently is:

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="internalFiles" path="/" />
    <external-path name="external" path="/" />
    <external-files-path name="exportFiles" path="/" />
    <external-media-path name="externalMedia" path="/" />
</paths>
```

Comment: `<external-files-path name="exportFiles" path="/" />` that should be `<external-files-path name="exportFiles" path="." />`

Answer (score 0):

file_paths.xml

```
<paths>
<external-files-path name="my_images" path="images/" />
</paths>
```

And make sure you have used above `path` while creating `file`. Like:

```
    @Throws(IOException::class)
private fun createImageFile(): File {
    // Create an image file name
    val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())


// Here I have used "images" because it is set as my path in file_paths.xml
   

 val storageDir: File? = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir("images")
    return File.createTempFile(
        timeStamp, /* prefix */
        ".jpg", /* suffix */
        storageDir /* directory */
    )
 }
```

Otherwise `exception` will be thrown while `uri` is passed in `intent` at

```
        val photoURI: Uri? = context?.let {
            try {
                createImageFile().let { file ->
                    FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        it,
                        requireContext().applicationContext.packageName.toString() + ".provider",
                        file
                    )

                }
            }catch (e: Exception){
                Log.d("TAG==>>","${e.localizedMessage}")
                null
            }
        }
        photoURI?.let {
            //currentImageUri = it

            val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, currentImageUri)
            startActivityForResult(intent,101) // replace with your request code
        }
```